Determining whether the sets $\{a\in\mathbb Z\mid0\leq a\leq10\}$ and $\{b\in\mathbb N\mid b^2\leq100\}$ are equal

Let $$A = \{a \in \mathbb Z\mid  0 \leq a \leq 10\}$$ and $$B = \{b \in \mathbb N \mid b^2 \leq 100\}$$ Determine
whether $A = B$. If they are equal, prove it. If they are not equal, provide a set
$A^\prime = A \cup \{x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$ containing additional elements $x_i \in \mathbb Z$ so that $A^\prime = B$, then prove
it.

I had this question on a quiz and my answer was marked incorrect. I wrote that since set $B$ does not include $0$, $B$ is a subset of $A$. Please help me solve it.

Is $-2$ in A?  In B?

@DavidG.Stork $-2$ is neither in $A$ nor $B$.

Well, what does b2 mean?  Makes no sense?

I agree with your solution but it depends upon how the natural numbers are defined in your class. Many consider zero to be a natural number

To determine if $A = B$, typically we see if $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$. In this case, we might be alarmed by the cardinalities alone of the sets. $A$ is finite while $B$ is countably infinite.
Can you think of a number $n$ such that $n \in B$ but $n \notin A$? For $n$ to be in $B$, we just need $2n \leq 100$.
To construct $A'$, you would need to see what elements of $B$ are missing in $A$ and construct a set of the missing elements to union with $A$ to construct $A'$. Then, prove $A' = B$ using the idea mentioned above.
I would advise you to see what numbers are in $B$ to get a better idea of the question being asked.
